# dialog tag not working in mozilla firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, dialog, mozilla

I am trying to make a popup dialog on my webpage without using bootstrap. I tried to use dialog jquery option. The problem i am facing is that the same code is working in chrome but not in mozilla firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
var pos = { of: window };
/////////
$(function() {
    $( "#my_dialog" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
position:pos,
 buttons: {
     "Close ": function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      },
     "Submit ": function(){
     $('#msg').html($("#f1").serialize());
     $( this ).dialog( "close" );
     }
   }
        });
});
/////////
$("#b1").click(function(){
$( "#my_dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
})
})
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Prompt</h2>

<button id="b1">Open Dialog Box</button><div id=msg></div>
<div id="my_dialog" title="plus2net  dialog"><form id=f1>
  <p>First Name<input type="text" id=t1 name=t1><br>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me! The same code :/. What functionality is missing in Firefox?

Comment: normal input field below button is coming on webpage when try to run on mozilla.